# Shower for a traveler passing through Delhi

Tags: india, hygiene, new-delhi

Since I have a bunch of flights and train rides that depart from Delhi, I go through the city quite a few times without the need of a room for the night. I'm interested whether there is a shower room/retiring room for a person who is staying in the city for a couple of hours.

I mostly have overnight trains and buses so that I don't have to pay for accommodation and I get to cover large distances that way without losing valuable time. The problem after an overnight ride is that I'm all [sweaty, smelly and in need of a refreshing shower](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_iLhCKMdQ-GQ/TTed4A6hjrI/AAAAAAAAAF4/G_SC4_2gt1E/s1600/quasimodo.jpg). Therefore I'm looking either for a cheap room or a place that offers just a shower for a passerby in New Delhi railway station area (3 km radius) and in the airport area. My requirement is that it has a hot water shower and not just a cold one or a bucket.

Comment: Why not Couch surf?

Comment: Because it would be awkward asking someone whether I can only use their shower for the afternoon.

Answer (score 11):

Yes! Many of the train stations in New Delhi have rooms that travelers can use for showers and sleep - they are called retiring rooms. They can only be booked at the station and are given on a first-come-first-serve basis.

Sorry, I am not familiar with facilities near the airport area.

Answer (score 7):

[There is Plaza premium lounge at T3 international departures that you can use.](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/premium-lounges.aspx) Three hour pass would cost US$30 and a six hour pass is around US$60 and a 12 hour pass would cost $85. Price included hot buffet and non alcoholic drinks. This lounge is after immigration and security so you would need to have your boarding pass to access the lounge.

There is one at domestic terminal as well and it costs lesser.

Comment: Do these have showers? Is there a website where we can find more information?

Comment: Yes they have showers , hot buffet and non alcholic drinks are included in the price  : http://www.newdelhiairport.in/shower-massage.aspx

Comment: Add that link and detail to the answer, make it at even better answer.

Comment: I inlined the link. It looks better. :)